# ASP.NET: Get file path on client's machine (Any possible solutions/work arounds?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a file upload control on .aspx page where I am extracting basic file information. The requirement is that I need to save absolute path for selected file from client's machine to a db.

I have read on this site as well as else where that by nature ASP.NET doesn't allow to read information from client's machine for security reason.

But I am wondering if there is a way around this issue using js or something to get the absolute path and then pass it to asp.net variables?

Comment: Why do you need the absolute path after uploading a file to server?

Comment: @Mithrandir - I belive interesting portion of the question is not "how to send it to server" but "how to consistently steal this information from the user".

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I want to save the path so that when user comes back on the site, on a list of files those were uploaded, they can see where the file is located on their machine.

Comment: @user1889838 Doesn't look like a good reason. The user can move the file to some other location or rename in their local system. In that case no benefit in storing path of the file in database. May be you should rethink your need.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really do anything reasonable about this restriction.

Any fully trusted code on users' machine can do that. So your goal is to convince user to install something that will provide you with the information.

For Windows (all require instalation of some sort):

- ActiveX controls
- Native EXE
- Locally installed managed EXE
- locally installed HTA for IE only

I believe almost all platforms also have ways to to so... with similarly painful installation requirements.

Comment: Thanks, Alexei Levenkov. Could you provide links for your suggested approaches?

Answer (score 2):

You can't get client machine path. For security purposes, the browser will never post the full file's path.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get full path of the file. 
For security purposes, the browser will never post the full file's path.

Try to use below code in java script.

```
lbltext.Text = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser send file without full file path, so to retrieve file path you do it on client side via javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnSubmitHandler(myForm)
{
   var fileUpload = document.getElementById('<% = FileUpload1.ClientID %>');


   myForm.action =  myForm.action + "?FilePath=" + fileUpload.value;


   return true;


}
</script>


<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server" onsubmit="return OnSubmitHandler(this);">
...
<asp:FileUpload id="FileUpload1" ....  />


...
</form>
```

If you don't want to send a file path via query string, you can create hidden form field, so file path will be sent via post.