# How to access selected file path and file name from save as dialog, in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, savefiledialog

I am using some Devexpress controls that have save options which open the browser download interface with the option of choosing "save as", opening the save as dialog. I want to save to the data base the file path and file name which were chosen for future reference. How can I access them from code behind? Also if the "save" option is chosen, how can I access the file path and name which were set by the system?

Thank you.

Comment: Why you need the client side path for saved file?

Comment: @Adil the file is part of information which the user is saving for his own future reference. Saving the path to the data base simplifies his finding the file or uploading it in the future when needed.

Comment: Browser wont tell you where user has saved file AFAIK, you can ask user to give you file path in some textfield

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET: Get file path on client's machine (Any possible solutions/work arounds?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153627/asp-net-get-file-path-on-clients-machine-any-possible-solutions-work-arounds)

Comment: @JimMSDN thank you but I want to download someting being made on the page. The file info is in the save as dialog popup and not in an asp.net or html control.

Comment: Agreed that that's what you _want_ to do, but it is something that would be a very large security risk if browsers _allowed you_ to do it.  Your options are I believe limited to the ones given in the question I referenced - all of which are Windows-specific and require some sort of client-type app to be developed.  I would personally look to eliminate this requirement unless it is absolutely, positively a show-stopper.